# Philippine passport holder stop over in Vancouver Canada

Tags: transit, transit-visas, layovers, stopovers

I hold a Philippine passport, with a C1 visa (transit visa to US). I had booked flights traveling back to Manila from Barbados.  My iterinary is from BGI to JFK, then on JFK New York then Cathay Pacific. I still need to stop over in YVR - Vancouver - Canada before heading to Hong Kong. Do I still need to have a transit visa from Canada , even will just stop over for 3hrs just to pick up passengers from there and heading to Hongkong?  Or am I eligible to TWOV transit without visa as holding a Philippine passport and have a C1 transit visa from US.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as you hold a Philippine passport and you are transiting to/from the US, through Vancouver airport, arriving on Cathay Pacific (one of the approved airlines), and you entered the US on a US visa and you did not overstay, you qualify for the [Transit Without Visa program](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/transit/without-visa/eligibility.html) which means you can transit Canada without a visa.